# pgAdmin4 dashboard does not display sessions

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I use pgadmin4.

In the dashboard the database sessions windows display an error message "an error occurred whilst rendering the graph"

Answer (score 3):

PgAdmin4 works fine with PostgreSQL 9.4+ version. Previous version of PostgreSQL (eg. 9.1) may have some problem as regards the display of the graph of the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Postgres database version?

What is your pgAdmin4 version?

Can you check in log for any errors?

> Linux log location: ~/.pgadmin/pgadmin4.log
>
> Windows log location: C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.log

if log size is large then delete the log file first then restart pgAdmin4.